# View Added Items in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I just began using Visual Studio to work on a practice .NET project. I have added a stylesheet that I made outside of VS. I went to Project/Add Existing Item... My question is, how can I view all the items I have added to a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to see all of your files in [Solution Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbck0dh6(VS.80).aspx), or are you asking about showing just the ones "added" to the project, not those "created" in the project?  I don't think there is a way to differentiate between the two once they are in the project.